# NodeJS PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large когда отправляю binary

Tags: node.js, express

Мне нужно написать обработчик для всех типов формы. Я проверяю работу через postman. То что я сейчас написал, работает для всех видов формы, кроме binary
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате запроса я получаю ошибку

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at rawParser (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/raw.js:81:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at next (/home/iskrayuriicr/projects/implement-echo-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
```

Мой код:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
const { raw } = express;
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 100000, limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.all('*',raw({type: '*/*'}), upload.array('files', 12), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({
    method: req.method,
    path: req.originalUrl,
    query: req.query,
    headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers),
    body: {
      fields: req.body,
      files: req.files
    },
  });
});


app.listen(port,(err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: А зачем вы вообще подключаете `body-parser`? Он у вас уже есть в `express` (и вы его даже используете). И собственно в `raw` вы не передаёте `limit`, а по умолчанию он 100kb.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а bodyParser можно использовать без подключения? вы имеете в виду строчку const bodyParser = require('body-parser');?

Comment: Я имею в виду https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw и соседние методы.
Т.е. `express.raw` это то же самое что `bodyParser.raw`, так что нет никакого смысла подключать его отдельно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, увеличил limit для raw, ошибка пропала. Но я заметил, что теперь когда есть raw, перестал работать multer. Не подскажете, как исправить можно?

Comment: Поменять порядок. У вас `raw` обрабатывает **любые** запросы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы raw обрабатывал все кроме каких-то запросов? Или несколько указать type? Ибо я прописал type: 'application/*' и теперь это работает для всех запросов, кроме text/html